# How to run executable from a different folder?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'm using the following 2 lines in my post build event command line for my VS C# project.

```
start xcopy "$(TargetPath)" "$(ProjectDir)..\..\..\Bin\" /R /Y /F /I
start xcopy "$(TargetDir)$(TargetName).xml" "$(ProjectDir)..\..\..\Bin\" /R /
```

It basically copies whatever executables, dll's, etc... are created and copies them to another folder. I am doing this because the other folder contains resources which this project needs and is shared by other people.

Currently, when I run the project, it runs the .exe inside /bin/debug.. not the one that is copied out to `other path`. How can i change this?

I want the project to run the executable from the different folder not /bin/debug. Thank you for any help.

Comment: Can't the resources be referenced *from* the other folder, instead of trying to move this *to* the other folder?

Comment: @David The project expects the resources to be in the same directory as the `.exe` so I don't think I can do that

Comment: What is the nature of these dependencies such that this expectation can't be changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Select your startup project in Solution Explorer
2. Right click `Properties`
3. Select Debug tab
4. Select option `Start external program` and enter relative or full path to your copied executable
   [image: 1]]

Alternatively, you can leave `Start project` option and configure Build->Output path to desired folder

[image]